# Let's delete the off topic questions?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, meta

There's like 5 in the top few of the front page and it's a little annoying as they get in the way so can a mod just delete them they serve no useful purpose.

Comment: I think this brings to light [this](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/56396/summer-2010-moderator-appointments/56498#56498) post of mine.

Comment: Or just bringing down the rep required to close questions seeing as this site is unique in that rep is not a key part (eg low acceptance is pretty unavoidable)

Comment: Anyone can vote to close. Maybe we need to make all users with >5k rep. have the ability to cast 'total' close votes which instantly close the question. (I can't remember the word for that.)

Comment: @George: No, you have to have a rep of 3000 to vote to close.

Comment: @Dennis: Sorry, I meant that anyone with 3k rep. can close.

Comment: check here http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/73300/stackapps-is-becoming-the-land-of-off-topic-closed-questions

Comment: I can't vote to close unless I'm missing something? Mod tools require 10k rep. I guess we could elect someone as a mod ourselves, get them to post a question and upvote it, and have them answer that question and upvote the answers until they reach 10k.